# Unable to mount VirtualBox share with Linux host and Windows guest

Tags: linux, virtualbox, linux-mint

I am running Linux Mint 12 and have installed the latest version of VirtualBox. I have installed Windows 7 as a guest. I have also created a share with the name `share`. I attempted to run the command `sudo mount -t vboxsf share /media/virtualshare` however get the error `/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device`.

I then ran the command `sudo insmod /lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/updates/vboxsf.ko` however got the error `insmod: error inserting '/lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/updates/vboxsf.ko': -1 Unknown symbol in module`.

I also ran the command `sudo modprobe vboxsf` and `sudo modprobe vboxvsf`. and was displayed the error `FATAL: Error inserting vboxsf (/lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/updates/vboxsf.ko): No such device`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I have also installed the VirtualBox Guest additions.

**EDIT**

Probably I don't understand this well enough but I came across an article agoing back to 2007 at https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=3201 and instead created a mount within Windows i.e. `net use M: \\vboxsrv\share` to the share and that worked!!!. Why? What does creating a share mean? I thought I am creating a share on Windows 7 and mounting the share from Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

> vboxsf share

with

> vboxsf foo

where foo is the name you share the folder under.

Answer (score 0):

Install paks onto a new installation in this order. Be sure to reboot after each instance!

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Install headers with kernel name (The second choice is better!):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) or
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic
```

Install gcc:

```
sudo apt-get install make gcc
```

Mount and install VboxGuestAdditions:

It will still say *Headers are not found* but when installed properly, sharing will work. You will now have a `/media/sf_MyShare` mounted (You have to auto mount the share in virtual box).

Now install

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

The problem is if you install DKMS first, it auto installs gcc and headers, but downloads the wrong versions.

Answer (score 0):

the `VirtualBox` create some shared folders via ssh protocol(maybe others), so it's like there are some devices pluged into your **virtual machine**.

i learnt that you're running as virtual **windows**, so your virtual windows was pluged some device from your `mint`, in this way, you need to mount the folder inside of the window, also, in the windows way.

that's why.